# Unable to receive email using postfix

Tags: bash, ubuntu, postfix, smtp

I am playing with the postfix to send an email from azure pipeline through a task. I use Ubuntu 20.04 in the pipeline. Here is the task I created where I have simple bash script.

```
sudo apt install mailutils

echo "Hello World" | mail -s "Sending email!" someemail@co.com

sudo tail -f /var/log/mail.log
```

When I run the pipeline , I get following:

Postfix (main.cf) is now set up with a default configuration.  If you need to
make changes, edit /etc/postfix/main.cf (and others) as needed.  To view
Postfix configuration values, see postconf(1).

After modifying main.cf, be sure to run 'systemctl reload postfix'.

```
Running newaliases
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/postfix.service → /lib/systemd/system/postfix.service.
Setting up guile-2.2-libs:amd64 (2.2.7+1-4) ...
Setting up libgsasl7:amd64 (1.8.1-1) ...
Setting up libmailutils6:amd64 (1:3.7-2.1) ...
Setting up mailutils (1:3.7-2.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/frm.mailutils to provide /usr/bin/frm (frm) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/from.mailutils to provide /usr/bin/from (from) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/messages.mailutils to provide /usr/bin/messages (messages) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/movemail.mailutils to provide /usr/bin/movemail (movemail) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/readmsg.mailutils to provide /usr/bin/readmsg (readmsg) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/dotlock.mailutils to provide /usr/bin/dotlock (dotlock) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/mail.mailutils to provide /usr/bin/mailx (mailx) in auto mode
Processing triggers for rsyslog (8.2001.0-1ubuntu1.3) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.36-6ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.21) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.9) ...
Jun 20 16:30:43 fv-az146-323 postfix/postfix-script[2701]: starting the Postfix mail system
Jun 20 16:30:43 fv-az146-323 postfix/master[2703]: daemon started -- version 3.4.13, configuration /etc/postfix
Jun 20 16:30:53 fv-az146-323 postfix/pickup[2704]: 12D29BFAB4: uid=1001 from=<vsts@fv-az146-323>
Jun 20 16:30:53 fv-az146-323 postfix/cleanup[4047]: 12D29BFAB4: message-id=<20230620163053.12D29BFAB4@fv-az146-323.zgw1fchrns0ulmuh1ptdxdixcf.ax.internal.cloudapp.net>
Jun 20 16:30:53 fv-az146-323 postfix/qmgr[2705]: 12D29BFAB4: from=<vsts@fv-az146-323>, size=451, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 20 16:30:55 fv-az146-323 postfix/smtp[4049]: 12D29BFAB4: to=<someemail@co.com>, relay=mxa-00198502.gslb.pphosted.com[185.132.180.7]:25, delay=2.2, delays=0.01/0.01/1.6/0.54, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 3rb8h1un11-1 Message accepted for delivery)
Jun 20 16:30:55 fv-az146-323 postfix/qmgr[2705]: 12D29BFAB4: removed
```

From this what I understand is that postfix has done its job to send email from from=<vsts@fv-az146-323. But since this from email does not exists , my company SMTP server must be assuming it to be spam and rejecting it ( This is my assumption since I did not receive any email nor any notification regarding failure)

How do I correct this? Can I somehow tweak postfix to update the from address so that my company SMTP server does not reject it?

Has anyone done this?

Comment: If your company is using any level of email security it will still block you. Look up SPF, DKIM, DMARC. Do **not** try sending as your company's domain.